# Difference in the latest and second-latest price

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables as follows:

```
Commodity
---------
Id        Name
1         Test 
2         SecondTest

CommodityPrice
--------------
Id      CommodityID    Price     EffectiveDate
0            1         0.66      05/01/2011
1            1         1.00      06/01/2011
2            1         1.50      07/01/2011
3            2         3.00      05/01/2011         
4            2         5.00      06/01/2011
5            2         10.00     07/01/2011
```

I'm attempting to write a query with the following output:

```
Result
-------
Name          PriceChange
Test          0.50
SecondTest    5.00
```

I've got this query which gets the most recent price, but it's not dealing with price differences yet.

```
SELECT c1.Name, cp1.Price
FROM Commodities c1
INNER JOIN CommodityPrices cp1
ON c1.Id = cp1.CommodityId
WHERE EffectiveDate = 
(SELECT MAX(cp2.EffectiveDate)
FROM CommodityPrices cp2
WHERE c1.Id = cp2.CommodityId);
```

I would like to find the price difference between the two most recent prices for a commodity. Note, that this should ignore prices earlier than the most recent two.

Comment: You want to vote for SQL Server to support the LEAD & LAG analytic functions: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/254388/over-clause-enhancement-request-lag-and-lead-functions

Comment: Voted! Now, any clues to solving this in the mean time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes SQL 2005 or later. Just use [ROW NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to assign numbers to the rows and then JOIN  `ON a.id = b.id AND b.rn = a.rn - 1`.

```
WITH
     cte 
     AS (SELECT c.id, 
                c.name, 
                cp.price, 
                cp.effectivedate, 
                Row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY c.id ORDER BY cp.effectivedate 
                DESC) 
                rn 
         FROM   commodity c 
                INNER JOIN commodityprice cp 
                  ON c.id = cp.commodityid) 
SELECT a.name, 
       b.price - a.price pricechange 
FROM   cte a 
       INNER JOIN cte b 
         ON a.id = b.id 
            AND b.rn = a.rn - 1 
WHERE b.rn = 1
```

Here's the sample data that I used

```
WITH Commodity as 
(           SELECT 1  as ID , 'Test' as name
 UNION ALL  SELECT 2, 'SecondTest'),
CommodityPrice as 
(   SELECT 1      as Id      , 1         as CommodityID , 1.00  as Price,    '06/01/2011' as EffectiveDate
    UNION ALL SELECT  2            ,1,         1.50      ,'07/01/2011'
    UNION ALL SELECT  4            ,2         ,5.00      ,'06/01/2011'
    UNION ALL SELECT  5            ,2         ,10.00     ,'07/01/2011'
UNION ALL SELECT  0            ,1         ,0.66      ,'05/01/2011'
UNION ALL SELECT  3            ,2         ,3.00      ,'05/01/2011'
 ),
```

Which produced this output

```
name       pricechange
---------- ---------------------------------------
Test       0.50
SecondTest 5.00

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Note: you could also drop `AND b.rn = a.rn - 1` from the `JOIN` and  add `AND a.rn = 2` to the `WHERE`

Comment: This is very close. The only issue is that if there are more than 2 price rows, I get multiple price change lines. I'll update my question to reflect this.

Comment: @Nick: You just need to add a filter on b.Rn = 1 and you will get the right result

Comment: @NickHeidke updated my answer. You just need to add `WHERE b.rn = 1`

Comment: You can probably use LAG to shorten the query, instead of using ROW_NUMBER.

Comment: @Vincent See OMG Ponies Comment on the question

Comment: @Conrad Thank you, I didn't see it earlier (and I didn't know SQL Server didn't support LAG/LEAD)

Answer (score 2):

Without ranking functions:

Test data:

```
declare @CommodityPrice table(id int identity, CommodityID int, Price money, EffectiveDate date)

insert @CommodityPrice(CommodityID, Price, EffectiveDate) 
    values (1, 0.66, '05/01/2011'), (1, 1, '06/01/2011'), (1, 1.5, '07/01/2011'),
        (2, 3, '05/01/2011'), (2, 5, '06/01/2011'), (2, 10, '07/01/2011')
```

Query:

```
select a.CommodityID, c2.Price - c1.Price
from
(
    select c1.CommodityID, MAX(c1.EffectiveDate) [m1], MAX(c2.EffectiveDate) [m2]
    from @CommodityPrice c1
    join @CommodityPrice c2 on c2.CommodityID = c1.CommodityID
        and c2.EffectiveDate > c1.EffectiveDate
        and not exists (
            select 1
            from @CommodityPrice c3
            where c3.EffectiveDate > c1.EffectiveDate and c3.EffectiveDate < c2.EffectiveDate
        )
    group by c1.CommodityID
)a
join @CommodityPrice c1 on c1.CommodityID = a.CommodityID and c1.EffectiveDate = a.m1
join @CommodityPrice c2 on c2.CommodityID = a.CommodityID and c2.EffectiveDate = a.m2
```